# Python print results which contains specific string in it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get google search result description.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=stackoverflow")
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("st")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```

Here Im getting correct results. 
But I only want to print links from description. 
And want to get results from 5 google search pages. 
Here I am only getting from 1 page.

I have tried using

```
print(post.get_attribute('href'))
```

but description links are not clickable so this returns None.

Comment: Are you sure you are grabbing data from correct locator? st class doesn't contain any links as I see. Maybe you need something like that: **posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[style='display:inline-block']")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
for i in range(1, 6, 1):
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Page "+str(i)+" Results : ")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
    staticLinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='st']")
    for desc in staticLinks:
        txt = desc.text+''
        if txt.count('http://') > 0 or txt.count('https://') > 0:
            for c in txt.split():
                if c.startswith('http') or c.startswith('https'):
                    print(c)

    dynamicLinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='st']//a")
    for desc in dynamicLinks:
        link = desc.get_attribute('href')
        if link is not None:
            print(link)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Page "+str(i+1)+"']");
    nextPage.click();
```

Will try to fetch the static & dynamic links from the google's first 5 search results description.

Comment: This is great. But I am not trying to get header link , I am trying to get link from result description.

Comment: Can you please share one example link with description, I mean, just want to know what is description and what links do you want from that?

Comment: Try the above code which will fetch and prints links from the description. Check for some other search results and confirm...

Comment: Yes this does work with stackoverflow. When Im trying to put this  driver.get("https://google.co.in/search?q=site:facebook.com friends https://chat.whatsapp.com")   this does not work.

Comment: Because those are not links, [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site:facebook.com%20friends%20chat.whatsapp.com) and there is no attribute 'href' in that description. This is like some static text, that's it. If you want for this page, then we can modify XPaths little bit.

Comment: with driver.find_elements_by_class_name("st") I was able to get full description, but I want to extract those chat links from description. Yes there is no 'href' I have mentioned that in question. It is static text.

Comment: Is there any way to extract those chat links. please ?

Comment: Yes, I have written the code. I'm posting, check and let me know

Comment: Just put `from selenium import webdriver
import re
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=stackoverflow")` before the for loop

Comment: Yes it worked. Been struggling from 2 days. Awesome. Great And Thank You.

Comment: Do suggest me some python course. In bangalore or pune ?

Comment: Welcome... It may not work for all the cases but you can change the code according to that.

Comment: Sorry! I don't have an idea on that.